# Creating a command substitution for each wildcard match

Tags: linux, bash

Imagine I have folder `foo` with files `a` and `b` (and maybe more).

I want to pass to `paste` a command substitution for *each* file in `foo` (here, the files `a` and `b`).

This is almost it:

```
paste <(cut -f1 /foo/*)
```

However, this expands to:

```
    paste <(cut -f1 /foo/a /foo/b)
```

While what I actually want is a separate substitution for every file in `foo`:

```
    paste <(cut -f1 /foo/a) <(cut -f1 /foo/b)
```

The solution doesn't have to involve command substitution necessarily, it's just how I formulated it.

Answer (score 4):

Your issue is that `<(command group)` implicitly creates a FIFO, but this FIFO only exists for the current command scope. It means, you cannot save this FIFO into a variable and come later to consume its stream. It has been released when its invoking command finished execution.

Lets demo this:

```sh
echo <(:) <(:); echo <(:)
```

Output:

```
/dev/fd/63 /dev/fd/62
/dev/fd/63
```

The second `echo` gets the sub-shell command group's allocated File Descriptor number reset.

An option instead is, explicitly creating named FIFO, as these lives until explicit deletion and so can their reference file name be saved for later use:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

tmpdir=$(mktemp -d)

trap 'rm -fr -- "$tmpdir"' EXIT

n=0

fifo_arr=()

for f in 'foo/'*; do
  fifo="$tmpdir/$((n++))"
  mkfifo "$fifo"
  fifo_arr+=("$fifo")
  cut -f1 "$f" >"$fifo" &
done

paste "${fifo_arr[@]}"
```

Comment: This is the level of wizardry I aspire to

Answer (score 2):

Alright, this is what I came up with.

```
ls *.txt | tr -s ' ' '\n' | sed -E 's/^(.*)$/<(cut -f1 \1)/' | tr -s '\n' ' ' | awk '{ print; }' > cmd.output; sed -i -E 's/^([^\s]+)/paste \1/' cmd.output; bash cmd.output
```

I have two files in my current directory, `a.txt` and `b.txt`.

The first contains only the following.

```
a
b
c
```

The second file is similar.

```
1
2
3
```

I begin by getting all of the files I'm interested in. For this example, it's all the `*.txt` files.

```
$ ls *.txt
a.txt b.txt
```

I then split each into it's own line by transcribing each space into a newline character (I suppose `col` works for this, too).

```
$ ls *.txt | tr -s ' ' '\n'
a.txt
b.txt
```

Next, I create the `cut` command for each of the listed files using a `sed` regex substitution.

```
$ ls *.txt | tr -s ' ' '\n' | sed -E 's/^(.*)$/<(cut -f1 \1)'
<(cut -f1 a.txt)
<(cut -f1 b.txt)
```

I now reverse the newline-space transcription to re-format this as a single line.

```
$ ls *.txt | tr -s ' ' '\n' | sed -E 's/^(.*)$/<(cut -f1 \1)'
<(cut -f1 a.txt) <(cut -f1 b.txt)
```

I then pipe this to a file, `cmd.sh` (I was using `tee` to see the results of my fiddling while experimenting.)

```
$ ls *.txt | tr -s ' ' '\n' | sed -E 's/^(.*)$/<(cut -f1 \1)' > cmd.sh
```

Having built up the command parameters, I then used another `sed` regex to edit the command file in place, replacing `<args>` with `paste <args>`.

```
$ sed -i -E 's/^([^\s]+)/paste \1/' cmd.sh
```

Before:

```
$ cat cmd.sh
<(cut -f1 a.txt) <(cut -f1 b.txt)
```

After:

```
$ cat cmd.sh
paste <(cut -f1 a.txt) <(cut -f1 b.txt)
```

Finally, I call `bash`, passing in the filename as an argument.

```
$ bash cmd.sh
a   1
b   2
c   3
```

I'm curious to see if anyone finds a better solution. This seems... hacky.